# Magento Errors after installation

Tags: php, magento, magento2

So I have just managed to download/setup Magento on XAMPP but I have no images on the back or front of the CMS. I have looked into the directories and there are no images where they should be.

I don't understand why this would be because I downloaded the files from the official website.

It's also running really slow :/

[image: Errors + front back end view.]

What could be causing how slow it is running and where would I get the images and missing js from? why would it be missing?

Comment: Have you compiled your static assets?

Comment: @RobbieAverill Not that i know of :/